# PHP remove non standard characters

Tags: php, character

I have text with alot of non-standard characters and they are stored like this in database:
`&#915;&#915;&#199;&#244;&#915;&#199;&#8359;&#915;&#915;&#199;&#244;&#915;&#199;&#8359;`

Is there a way to filter them or replace them with nothing?

Comment: Is this really what you want? Would it not be a better idea to turn them into actual characters?

Comment: Define "non-standard characters". Any entity? Anything non-ASCII? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to delete them, not turn them into actual characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

```
echo preg_replace("/&#\\d+;/", "", $textWithWeirdCharacters);
```

Comment: @Jack np, remember this will *erase* all characters. They where probably put there by someone. Erasing them might make the text hard or impossible to read. Also consider converting the characters, this will also avoid any type of decoding-problems you might have causing you to wanting to remove those characters.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array with the non-standard characters you don't want. And then apply next code to it.

```
<?php
$blockChars = array('&#915', '...');
$string = str_replace($block, array_fill(0, count($blockChars), ''), $string);
?>
```